# Gitworkflow to manage multiple versions and hotfixes

Tags: git, maven, gitlab, git-flow

We have a git repository with a master branch.
All devs create a feature branch from master and commit back to it.
Once we are ready for release we create a tag on master and create a release from it.
The release(an ear) is then deployed on acceptance. Once validated, the same ear is deployed in prod.
If there's any issue on acceptance env, we create another branch from master and then merge it back to master. Then we follow the same release process.

This usually works fine most of the time, however since the master is not always same as the production version (devs merge feature branches directly to master), delivering hotfixes before the next major release is a challenge. The <s>semver</s> version for a major release is always X.Y.Z.0, X.Y.Z+1.0, X.Y.Z+2.O etc.

Right now we create a hotfix branch from the tag(the one in prod, not the most recent tag) and fix it and release it as a separate branch. It then goes to ack again and then gets validated and goes to prod. The <s>semver</s> version for hotfixes  is X.Y.Z.1, X.Y.Z.2.... etc.

Once hotfix is validated, we deploy the ear in prod. Then we merge the hotfix into master. The merge has to be done manually since the pom version of hotfix and master is different.

Is there a better way to manage this?

I have explored Git-flow and other similar flows, but they don't really address this issue as they all consider master to be the single source of truth for production, which is not the case for us.

We can create more branches if that helps us. We use Gitlab.

Comment: Can you explain this: `All devs create a feature branch from master and commit back to it.` more in detail? Are you using merge ? You deliver a state (EAR) to acceptance/prod making a tag.. So you should make a fix based on the tag because in the meantime your master branch can change (continued development)...merging the bug fix branch back into master..Hot fixes can only being made based on the state of a release branch and hot fixing that over the time...merging back those hot fixes to master...

Comment: Furthermore what I don't understand is `The semver for a major release is always X.Y.Z.0, X.Y.Z+1.0, X.Y.Z+2.O etc.` .. semver has three parts `Major.Minor.Patch` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise For your first comment. Yes we use merge to merge the feature branch back to master. And Yes after each release we create a tag. And yes, we create a hotfix from the tag and NOT the master. Once delivered to prod we merge the hotfix branch back to master so the master = prod + new dev.

For your second comment. My bad. I just realized it can have 3 digits. Yes, in addition to three digits we have a fourth digit. This is incremented only in case of hotfixes or if there are issues in acceptances.

Comment: Why not using semver where the last digit is intended for patched/bug fixes... ?

Comment: It's an existing setup. I have already spoken to the business, but they want to keep things 'complicated'.